# Count XML element Value

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Im Trying to count Value in Team Element throw all Xml nodes and populate it to List box in this format: Team1, Count 3.
Thnx for help

```
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Team");
        foreach (XmlNode xNode in nodeList)
        {
            foreach (var item in xNode)
            {
                lstRegPartiData.Items.Add(xNode.InnerText + item);   
            }
        }
```

Here im try to count elements by value.

And this is my xml template.

```
           <Participants>
              <Participant>
                <DateTime>21.04.2018</DateTime>
                <FullName>N1</FullName>
                <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
                <Phone>123456789</Phone>
                <DateOfBirth>00/00/1988</DateOfBirth>
                <Team>Team1</Team>
                <MainWeapon>T1</MainWeapon>
                <MainWeaponChrono>120-130 m\s</MainWeaponChrono>
                <WeaponClass>C1</WeaponClass>
                <Comment>Hello World</Comment>
              </Participant>
              <Participant>
                <DateTime>21.04.2018</DateTime>
                <FullName>N1</FullName>
                <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
                <Phone>987654321</Phone>
                <DateOfBirth>00/00/1988</DateOfBirth>
                <Team>Team1</Team>
                <MainWeapon>T1</MainWeapon>
                <MainWeaponChrono>120-130 m\s</MainWeaponChrono>
                <WeaponClass>C1</WeaponClass>
                <Comment>My Comment</Comment>
              </Participant>
               <Participant>
                <DateTime>21.04.2018</DateTime>
                <FullName>N1</FullName>
                <Email>email@gmail.com</Email>
                <Phone>123456789</Phone>
                <DateOfBirth>00/00/1988</DateOfBirth>
                <Team>Team1</Team>
                <MainWeapon>T1</MainWeapon>
                <MainWeaponChrono>120-130 m\s</MainWeaponChrono>
                <WeaponClass>C1</WeaponClass>
                <Comment>Hello World</Comment>
              </Participant>
            </Participants>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
readDoc.Load(@"XML.xml");
var Node = readDoc.SelectNodes("Participants/Participant/Team");
Dictionary<string, int> teamList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (XmlNode n in Node)
{
    if (teamList.ContainsKey(n.InnerText))
        teamList[n.InnerText]++;
    else
        teamList.Add(n.InnerText, 1);
}
```

i know its not look good but it should work

Comment: BINGO!, thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose your `xml` is something like:

```
<Root>
<Team name="team1">
 <Participants>
              <Participant> 
              </Participant>
              <Participant>

              </Participant>
               <Participant>

              </Participant>
 </Participants>
</Team>
<Team name="team2">
 <Participants>
              <Participant> 
              </Participant> 
              <Participant> 
              </Participant>
 </Participants>
</Team>
</Root>
```

then change your code to:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"your xml path");
var teams = xdoc.Descendants("Team");
foreach (XElement team in teams)
{
    var firstElement = team.Elements();//Get all elements, here is only one element
    var participants = firstElement.Elements();
    int teamCount = participants.Count();
    var teamName = team.FirstAttribute.Value;
    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} contains {1} member(s)...", teamName, teamCount); 
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

notes:

1- Each `xml` file must have one root element not more, here is `<Root>`.

2- I supposed there is one element in each `team` element so the `team.Elements()` give you all elements.

3- I supposed there is an attribute for each `team` element named `name` so the `team.FirstAttribute.Value` give you the `name` of `team` element, otherwise you should use something like `team.Attributes("name")` to get attribute.

Comment: Hey, thanx for you answer, but,unfortunately, XML structure cannot be changed.

Comment: So provide a complete sample of that, nit a part, edit the question an post your xml sample completely.

Comment: But it is not complete, because you asked about iterating `team` element and count `Participant` for them.